Has anyone tried to capture the ON DELETE CASCADE changes that happen in the child tables in Mysql for Auditing purposes?
I am currently working on a project to log all the deletes that occur in the child tables when a parent record is deleted.Since the mysql binlogs(for InnoDB engine) only capture the deletion of the parent node, parsing the binlog does not give all the database changes for auditing purpose.Has anyone tried to overcome this problem.Debezium also does not capture the deletions.
